# Dynamic ArcServer Layer

Tags: arcgis-server, openlayers-2

I have the following setup:

ArcGIS Server + ArcSDE on top of Oracle RAC.

I created a view merging some data that is in Oracle and ArcSDE. In ArcMap it all works just fine. Whenever a new location is added to the locations table, I can see the joined features, etc.

However I need this to happen in ArcServer. I mean, I have a MSD published and I can consume it via REST and OpenLayers. It seems to me that AGS is caching the generated tiles, although it's set to NOT cache anything.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: If you use the REST admin tool to clear the cache, do the locations appear?

Comment: Maybe your browser is caching the image returned by the service image? I've not used AGS services with OL. The Esri JS API has a parameter, disableClientCaching, on dynamic map service layers. Does openlayers have that parameter? http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer.htm#disableClientCaching

Comment: Derek, please post your answer as...an answer...so I can award you the points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your browser is caching the image returned by the service? I've not used AGS services with OL. The Esri JS API has a parameter, [disableClientCaching](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer.htm#disableClientCaching), on dynamic map service layers. Does openlayers have that parameter?

Comment: Clearing browser cache solved the issue. Still looking for the correspondent OL solutions, since in my service demonstrtion page created with ESRI JS API it works fine.